# Styling Jquery Datepicker trigger icon

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Here is the code that I am using for my Jquery datepicker:

```
<div class="span3" style="display:inline;">
    <input type="text" id="filter-date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>"/>
</div>

$(function() {
    $( "#filter-date" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true
    });
  });
```

I've tried looking at similar questions here on Stack Overflow but I can't get the trigger image to appear inline with the input. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Also where can I get a calender icon to use for the trigger?

Comment: The path you specify for the buttonImage parameter is probably wrong. Which browser are you using during development? Can you do an 'inspect element' on the image that does not show and see what path it's using? You haven't given much information for us to work with here.

Comment: You can get an icon from anywhere, but it's not included with jQuery UI. Just make sure your path to the image you use is correct.

Comment: Try `buttonImage: "/images/calendar.gif",`

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason your image is not displaying inline with your textbox is because it's being wrapped down to the next line because of its container's limited width. Decrease the size of your textbox, or increase the size of your container.